# Are there Dwemer ruins in High Rock?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series

I'm currently trying to put together the backstory for my Skyrim character. She's a Breton, who was born in High Rock. I've been thinking about including in her backstory that she lost her mother in a Dwemer ruin, and have been trying to find out whether or not there is any evidence of there being Dwemer ruins in High Rock.

I have found that both the [Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dwemer_Ruins) and the [Unofficial Elder Scrolls Page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:High_Rock) state that there are indeed Dwemer ruins in High Rock, but other sources are saying that there aren't any.

Are there any Dwemer ruin in High Rock?

Comment: You give us sources that there is.. what are your sources that there are not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, there are Dwemer ruins in High Rock. [Zthenganaz](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Zthenganaz) is one of them.**

---

### [The Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dwemer_Ruins)

> Dwemer ruins are the remains of Dwemer cities, which scattered across Skyrim,<sup>[source]</sup> Hammerfell, **High Rock,<sup>[source]</sup>** and Morrowind.

Which credits the statement to the in-game lore book, [Dwemer Inquiries Vol II](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dwemer_Inquiries_Vol_II). While the lore book does not mention High Rock, itself, that is to be expected. The book acts as a translation of Dwemer texts, who did not refer to "High Rock" using its more modern name. With my limited knowledge of the Dwemer lore, the only connection I can make is in reference to the Dewmer ruins of [Bthardamz](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Bthardamz);

> The largest and most impressive Venues, **such as that found in Bthardamz**, may even feature roads wide enough for ten large men to walk shoulder-meets-shoulder along it.

Bthardamz is in [The Reach](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Reach), a hold within Skyrim. However, The Reach backs on to High Rock - into an area of High Rock called the [Western Reach](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Western_Reach). It is safe to assume that the Western Reach connects with the Reach, given that it is in *Eastern* High Rock, but directly west of The Reach.

This train of argument still relies on speculation, but it is obvious that Western Reach and The Reach share more then mere proximity.

### [The Unofficial Elder Scrolls Page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:High_Rock)

The lore provided on High Rock does not seem to offer any contradiction, in this case:

> **Wrothgar is the northeastern region of High Rock.** .. It also contains numerous Orc strongholds and **Dwemer ruins.**

### The Elder Scrolls Online

[High Rock is actually a location](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/High_Rock_%28Online%29), in The Elder Scrolls Online. One of its regions, in particular, look particularly interesting. Here is an excerpt from [the trivia section of The Elder Scrolls Wiki page concerning the High Rock found in The Elder Scrolls Online](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/High_Rock_%28Online%29#Trivia):

> The Regions in Wrothgar are Pseudonyms created to give each Sub-Region a proper name. The Western Reach is the snowy western portion of The Reach **named because of the Dwemer Ruins in the region.**

Ultimately, we can say that at least one Dwemer Ruin exists within High Rock:

- [Zthenganaz](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Zthenganaz) is a Dwemer Ruin that is located in Wrothgar, in the region of High Rock. The ruins are a location in The Elder Scrolls Online: Orsinium, and feature during the quest [An Unexpected Fall](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/An_Unexpected_Fall).

Comment: It's worth noting that there are no Dwemer ruins in *The Elder Scrolls II: Daggerfall*, which takes place in High Rock. The Dwemer weren't introduced until *The Elder Scrolls III: Morrowind*, and it has since been retconned that High Rock has always had Dwemer ruins.